# why I am having double brackets in json

Tags: android, json

why I am having double '[[' ?
should it be one bracket ? '['

> [[{"name":"50 shade of
>   gray","path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg","description":"long
>   story","likes":"5","comments":" Very
>   nice"},{"name":"Transformers","path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2jpg","description":"Robots","likes":"7","comments":"
>   beautiful"},{"name":"Avangeers","path":"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/3.jpg","description":"hulk
>   and iron man","likes":"8","comments":" wow"}]]

this is my php

```
$sql = "select name , path , description , likes , comments from image ";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('name'=>$row[0],
'path'=>$row[1],
'description'=>$row[2],
'likes'=>$row[3],
'comments'=>$row[4]
));
}


echo json_encode(array($result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

And is it correct getting it in such code ?

```
   JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("r", response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        System.out.print(response);

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("path"));
                                movie.setRating(obj.getString("description"));
                              //  movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("description"))
                                    //    .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getString("likes"));
                              //  movie.setYear(obj.getInt("likes"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("comments");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.print(error);
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Because probably you're pushing an array to another empty array. That may cause double brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is an array. 
You push associative arrays (that become objects) in that array, so now you have `[{...},{...}]`

Then you do:

```
echo json_encode(array($result));
```

so you get an array with an array in it, resulting in the above result with extra '[' around: `[[{...},{...}]]`